# Problem setting $primary color in buefy with bulma

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, bulma, buefy

Buify bulma problem in vue2

I have trouble setting $primary color with buify / bulma.

The problem seems to be that the change ends up in the generated css file
The default color is purple # 7957d5
I have set the variable $ primary to pink # 3e912ba

For exactly the same element, it generates several different colors where the standard is in line 14617 min change of 12241
See blue arrow ->

[image: css inspector of the dom]

Tho whole set up is:

- VUE 2 “vue”: “^2.6.11”,
- SASS DART “sass”: “^1.26.5”, “sass-loader”: “^8.0.2”,
- Buefy “buefy”: “^0.9.10”,
- Import bulma

In the SCSS file I set the colorvariabels for buefy with bulma as in [the offical doc](https://buefy.org/documentation/customization)

```
    @import '~bulma/sass/utilities/all';
// Set your colors
$primary: #e912ba;
$primary-light: findLightColor($primary);
$primary-dark: findDarkColor($primary);
$primary-invert: findColorInvert($primary);
$twitter: #4099FF;
$twitter-invert: findColorInvert($twitter);

// Lists and maps
$custom-colors: $primary;
$custom-shades: null !default;

// Setup $colors to use as bulma classes (e.g. 'is-twitter')
$colors: mergeColorMaps(
    (
        "primary": (
            $primary,
            $primary-invert,
            $primary-light,
            $primary-dark,
        ),
      
    ),
    $custom-colors
);

// Links
$link: $primary;
$link-invert: $primary-invert;
$link-focus-border: $primary;

// Import Bulma and Buefy styles
@import '~bulma';
@import '~buefy/src/scss/buefy';
```

in the app.vue I import the scss

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "./css/style.scss";
</style>
```

three different css files is generated, where the first in the head is the one where the changes I make in $primary is saved. The last one is where I find the defualt-value for buefy $primary color.

[image: head link css-sheets]

Comment: Have you tried putting that SCSS code inside the `<style>` tags in `app.vue` instead of in its own file?

Comment: I tried it now, but it dont work

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem was that I in the main.js file imported the buefy.css
`import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css'`
when I removed this it worked.

Comment: That makes sense because it would have loaded the Buefy styles in `main.js` before it loads `app.vue`.